# Сложить два элемента (два числа) массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Привет. Вроде элементарно, но как сложить два элемента массива, содержащие "number". При складывании они слепляются, а не складываются, например, 3 + 2 = 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем ясен. Складываются только строки. Возможно надо было их просто "привести" к числу (`+'3' === 3`).

```
var arr = ['1','2',3,'4',5],
sum = arr.reduce(function (prevSum, summand) {
  return +prevSum + +summand;
});

console.log(sum);
```

[reduce](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright)